# How to show blogger posts randomly on homepage?

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I want to show my blogger (blogspot) homepage posts in a random order. By default, usually blogger posts are sorted by date. There are widgets to place in blogger layout but I want to change this on the main pages posts. Is there any way I can do this by editing html?